# How to always get English font name via PrivateFontCollection in C#?

Tags: c#, privatefontcollection

Now I am getting the font name by the following code:

```
PrivateFontCollection fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
fontCollection.AddFontFile("path_to_my_Thai_font");
return fontCollection.Families[0].Name;
```

On a English Win7 system, I get "DFPHeiMedium-UN", but on a Chinese Win7 system, I get "華康中黑體(P)-UN".
So, the font name differs in different system languages.

My question is how to write my code to make sure that I can always get "DFPHeiMedium-UN" regardless of the system language?

Thank you.

By the way, I tried CurrentCulture. I put this line before the above code. Still don't work.
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`GetName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontfamily.getname(v=vs.110).aspx) function which accepts a language identifier, or 0 for the neutral language:

```
PrivateFontCollection fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
fontCollection.AddFontFile("path_to_my_Thai_font");
return fontCollection.Families[0].GetName(0);
```

As to why you culture change didn't work, we can look at the implementation of [`Name` in the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/FontFamily.cs,305):

```
    public String Name 
    {
        get 
        {   
            return GetName(CurrentLanguage);
        }
    }
```

And if we inspect [`CurrentLanguage`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/FontFamily.cs,256), we can see that it's using `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID`, that is, the current *UI* culture, rather than `CurrentCulture`.